# How to add InnerBlock multiple times in the same block

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

When I click a button to add a new tab, I would like to have an `<InnerBlock />` so I can add other blocks within the tab. Trying this does not work as the same  seems to be in all the dynamically created tabs.

```
import "./index.css";
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  RichText,
  InnerBlocks,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Button } from "@wordpress/components";
const __ = wp.i18n.__;

registerBlockType("custom/tabs", {
  title: __("Tabbed Blocks", "custom-blocks"),
  description: __("Tabbed content blocks", "custom-blocks"),
  icon: "smiley",
  category: "custom-category",
  keywords: [__("tabs", "custom-blocks"), __("repeat", "custom-blocks")],
  attributes: {
    tabs: {
      type: "array",
      default: [""],
    },
  },

  edit: (props) => {
    const {
      attributes: { tabs },
      setAttributes,
    } = props;

    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);

    const onTabClick = (index) => {
      setCurrentTab(index);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div className="simple-tabs">
          <div className="tabs">
            {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
              <RichText
                tagName="button"
                value={tab}
                className={currentTab == index ? `active` : ""}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  const newTabs = tabs.concat([]);
                  newTabs[index] = newValue;
                  setAttributes({ tabs: newTabs });
                }}
                onClick={() => onTabClick(index)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>

          {tabs.map((tab, index) => {
            if (index == currentTab) {
              //return <div>Tab content {index}</div>;
              return <InnerBlocks />;
            }
          })}
        </div>
        <Button
          isPrimary
          onClick={() => {
            setAttributes({ tabs: tabs.concat([""]) });
          }}
        >
          Add Tab
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  },
  save: (props) => {
   return <InnerBlocks.Content />;
  },
});
```

Desired output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't**

That's not how blocks work, and it's not how HTML works. If you want multiple areas to insert blocks into, you need multiple blocks.

This is the same as saying that a box has multiple insides, or that there is more than one "inside a HTML tag", it does not make sense as a concept.

Instead, do what the official core blocks do. E.g Columns.

- Columns block

  - column

    - paragraph
    - paragraph
  - column

    - paragraph
    - paragraph

A columns block can only contain individual column blocks, and it's the individual column blocks that contain the content.

[image]

Tabs would work the same:

- Tabs

  - tab

    - paragraph
    - paragraph
  - tab

    - paragraph
    - paragraph

Notice as well that what you're asking for is also not possible to represent in bullet points without accidentally coming up with the exact same solution.

It's the same with HTML tags, if I want to have a `<div>` container with 2 internal spaces I have to put 2 tags inside it to act as the separate spaces. Why would blocks be any different.

Note that the block appender UI is just the default UI, and nothing prevents you passing a custom appender component to the inner blocks UI, or even building one into the block itself.

Here's an example taken straight from the readme for the InnerBlocks components appender attribute doc:

```
// Utilise a predefined component
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={ InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender }
/>

// Don't display an appender
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={ false }
/>

// Fully custom
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={ MyAmazingAppender }
/>
```

Here's an appender component:

```
function render( { clientId } ) {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Some rendered content here</p>
            <ButtonBlockAppender rootClientId={ clientId } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/button-block-appender

Here is how the tabs block from ultimate GB addons does it:

```
        const { insertBlock } = !wp.blockEditor ? dispatch( 'core/editor' ) : dispatch( 'core/block-editor' );
        const tabItemBlock = createBlock('uagb/tabs-child');

        insertBlock(tabItemBlock, attributes.tabHeaders.length, clientId);
```

Here they use a `uaggb/tabs` block to provide the UI and contain the tabs, and a `uaggb/tabs-child` block to contain the content of each tab and provide tab specific attributes

Useful links:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/
- https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks/README.md

Comment: I included notes on the appender based on your previous question. You need to approach this step by step, don't throw out the correct next step because you cannot see how you will make the final two steps, you can always ask new questions!

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will go through this in detail later when I get a gap. You may have addressed everything as I haven't had chance to read it yet but I just attached two images from another plugin I installed to show you what I mean. They are doing exactly what I am trying to do in that you can add more tabs within the same block and then add InnerBlocks into each tab. I don't have to add a new tab block for each tab.

Comment: If you want to see a working demo of the tabs in my screenshot you can just download the free plugin to see https://ultimategutenberg.com

Comment: they're doing exactly what I've suggested you do, a `tabs` block and a `tabs-child` block, although their implementation is not great ( rather than using the child blocks to render the tabs, they're storing them as an attribute and doing DOM manipulation to set the order which is a huge red flag ), otherwise they're using the insertblocks functions to add new tabs as I suggested https://github.com/brainstormforce/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg/blob/master/src/blocks/tabs/edit.js

Comment: Right, either I am starting to understand or am I even worse off than when I started :) Would a first step be to create a `tabs` block which I basically add a 'tab' to and then inside the 'tab' I can have whatever content in there? So, the tabs block would just be something like this: `<div>
        <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={["my-custom-blocks/tab]} />
      </div>` I can then click the plus button to my hearts content and it will keep adding the tab block

Comment: that's exactly what you need to do, you're on the right track! It'll show them in a vertical list and give you a default appender, you can replace the appender with your own, the listing the tabs part is a little less common of a task so that'd actually make a great next question to ask. Showing the current tab sounds like a great excuse to make use of the context API. When you open the next question drop a link here :) A tabs block is a little more complex than what most people build, but once you've done it you'll be in a great position

Comment: Hey Tom, I added a new question and here is the link :) I can only hope I am on the right track. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398509/custom-gutenberg-tabs-structure-and-styling